# Can I view the command line to be executed in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to diagnose an issue I am having with IntelliJ 10.0.2 not being able to launch a run configuration due to an (potentially) excessively long command line. It is an 'OSGI Bundles' configuration using the Equinox Framework.

I would like to be able to get the command line that Idea is trying to execute so I can diagnose the issue but I'm not sure how to.

The 'run' tool window does not open but a tooltip appears above the 'run' tool window tab stating that the command line is too long and that this could potentially be solved by enabling a classpath file. However 'dynamic.classpath' has already been enabled and is working (I can run my unit tests only with this set to true).

Any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't use a CLASSPATH in the command used to launch an app in IntelliJ.  I add all the JARs I need as libraries when I configure the module.  If those are making your run command unnecessarily long, perhaps using IntelliJ as it is intended will sort you out.

Comment: An interesting alternative to manually add the classpath myself but as you suggested, I am indeed using a collection of libraries associated with the module which, I thought, are then added to the classpath by intellij on application launch